# Does hibernate search support nested query or has_child and has_parent query?

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I have been searching to find out nested query support in hibernate search but unable to get.Can anybody tell me is there any support in hibernate search?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. It's coming in Hibernate Search 6, though.

EDIT: A bit more information. The relevant ticket in our JIRA tracker is [HSEARCH-2263](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2263); we will update it as the feature makes its way to the master branch.
Also, there is no planned release date for Search 6 yet (it's still in its early days).